# How do I disable auto maximize?

Tags: windows-7, google-earth

I use multiple monitors with multiple applications open simultaneously.  I'm having this problem with only one application window (in Google Earth).  When I turn maximize off on that window, and then resize the window, it auto maximizes.

I like the options for docking to the sides and top so I don't want to turn that off; I just want to be able to resize this one window when not maximized.

Every other window is working fine.  Every fix I've been able to find involves turning these options off through the ease of access center and checking "Prevent windows form being automatically arranged..." but I'm just having the problem in one window.

Thanks

Comment: If it's only affecting a single application, then it might be relevant to THAT application. Knowing what it is would go a long way to us being able to provide "more better" guesses ;)

Comment: I'm using Google Earth

Comment: It is probably switching from small window a full 3D "screen" not window , much like a 3D rendered game would be doing. I assume they are using this method more often because it causes less problematic video issues.  Like has been stated before it is the program itself that determines how that works. See if you can find an option to run "windowed" in the options of the program itself first?

Comment: I haven't been able to find such an option.  I've been using Google Earth for years without any problems until this recently.

Comment: yes, not seeing it.